# Using win32gui to center a window

Tags: python, win32gui

I am teaching myself how to automate Windows applications with python and have hit a slight snag.  I want to open calc.exe, bring it to the foreground, and then center it on the screen so I may use static coordinates to manipulate the calculator.  I can't seem to figure out why the window won't center with `win32gui.MoveWindow`.

How can I modify my code below to center the window?

```
#Encapsulates some calls to with Winapi for window management
class WindowMgr:

    #Constructor
    def __init__ (self):
        self._handle = None

    #Find the window by its class name
    def find_window(self, class_name, window_name=None):
        self._handle = win32gui.FindWindow(class_name, window_name)

    #Pass to win32gui.EnumWindows() to check all of the open windows
    def _window_enum_callback(self, hwnd, wildcard):
        if re.match(wildcard, str(win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))) is not None:
            self._handle = hwnd

    #Find a window that matches the title of the wildcard regex
    def find_window_wildcard(self, wildcard):
        self._handle = None
        win32gui.EnumWindows(self._window_enum_callback, wildcard)

    #Put the window in the foreground
    def set_foreground(self):
        win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(self._handle)

    #Move the window to center screen
    def move_to_center(self):
        w_wid = int(screenWidth/2)
        w_len = int(screenHeight/2)
        win32gui.MoveWindow(self._handle, 0, 0, w_wid, w_len, 0)

w = WindowMgr()
w.find_window_wildcard(".*Calc.*")
w.set_foreground()
w.move_to_center()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working, here is what I figured out in case its helpful.

```
def enumHandler(hwnd, lParam):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        if 'Calculator' in win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd):
            win32gui.MoveWindow(hwnd, screenWidth/3, screenHeight/3, 0, 0, True)

win32gui.EnumWindows(enumHandler, None)
```

Comment: FYI to anybody searching here. You can find some examples of doing this here: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/89823/win32gui.MoveWindow